# Prove that given number is integer

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I have bumped into one simple task which I am not able to prove:

How to prove, that number $ \frac{1000!}{(100!)^{10}} $ is integer?

Comment: $(100\cdot 10)!$ is divisible by  $100!^{10}$ by the duplicate.

Comment: ok sorry as I see there is already same questions, ty lads anyway sry for stupidness

Answer (score 1):

The given number is a multinomial coefficient, which is always an integer.